# how to show when a value is zero or below

Tags: javascript

I am busy whith a monopaly game.It is almost done but I cant find out how to 
show when the user is bankrupt

I would prefer to use my isBankrupt function to check if the persons money is less then or equal to zero, if so it sould log that that user is bankrupt
I have tried  including an if statement in my  dice function but it is not working.

```
let player = [
  {
    name: "",
    money: 1000,
    position: 0,
    propertys: [
      {
        name: "raslow",
        position: 2,
        cost: 20
      },
      {
        name: "luadiam",
        position: 4,
        cost: 50
      },
      {
        name: "eldo",
        position: 6,
        cost: 100
      },
      {
        name: "erasmia",
        position: 8,
        cost: 200
      }
    ],
    dice() {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      for (var i = 0; i < player[0].propertys.length; i++) {
        if (random === player[0].propertys[i].position) {
          console.log("you are safe");
          break;
        } 
        else if (random == 1 || random == 10) {
          console.log("you are safe");
          break;
        } 
        else if(random !== player[0].propertys[i].position){
          if (random === 3) {
            console.log("you have landed on Columbus");
            player[0].money -= 20;
            player[1].money += 20;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 5) {
            console.log("you have landed on  Essex");
            player[0].money -= 50;
            player[1].money += 50;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 7) {
            console.log("you have landed on Eugene ");
            player[0].money -= 100;
            player[1].money += 100;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 9) {
            console.log("you have landed on Diego ");
            player[0].money -= 200;
            player[1].money += 200;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(player[0].name + ' ' + "has" + " " + player[0].money);
      console.log(player[1].name + ' '+ "has" + " " + player[1].money);
    },
    isBankrupt(){
     while(player[0].money <= 0){
      console.log(player[0].name + ' ' + 'is Bankrupt')
     }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "",
    money: 1000,
    position: 0,
    property: [
      {
        name: "Columbus",
        position: 3,
        cost: 20
      },
      {
        name: "Essex",
        position: 5,
        cost: 50
      },
      {
        name: "Eugene",
        position: 7,
        cost: 100
      },
      {
        name: "Diego",
        position: 9,
        cost: 200
      }
    ],
    dice() {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      for (var i = 0; i < player[0].propertys.length; i++) {
        if (player[1].money <= 0) {
          break;
        }
        if (random === player[0].propertys[i].position) {
          console.log("you are safe");
          break;
        } 
        else if (random == 1 || random == 10) {
          console.log("you are safe");
          break;
        } 
        else if(random !== player[0].propertys[i].position) {
          if (random === 2) {
            console.log("you have landed on raslow");
            player[0].money += 20;
            player[1].money -= 20;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 4) {
            console.log("you have landed on luadiam ");
            player[1].money -= 50;
            player[0].money += 50;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 6) {
            console.log("you have landed on eldo ");
            player[1].money -= 100;
            player[0].money += 100;
            break;
          }
          if (random === 8) {
            console.log("you have landed on erasmia ");
            player[1].money -= 200;
            player[0].money += 200;
            break;
          }
        }

      }
      console.log(player[0].name + ' ' + "has" + " " + player[0].money);
      console.log(player[1].name + ' ' + "has" + " " + player[1].money);
    },
        isBankrupt(){
     while(player[0].money <= 0){
      console.log(player[0].name + ' ' + 'is Bankrupt')
     }
    }

  }
];
function playgame() {
    player[0].name = prompt('Enter player1 name')
    player[1].name = prompt('Enter player2 name')
}
```

Please help out

Comment: Why are you checking for player[1].money<=0 in a for loop.Simply put it out of the loop and make a conditional statement.with the for loop code in the else part.

Comment: replace the `while` loop by a simple `if` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for bankruptcy with a simple `if` statement:

```
if (player[0].money <= 0) {
  console.log(player[0].name + ' ' + 'is Bankrupt');
}
```

If you want to put it into a function so that you can call it for each player -- instead of writing multiple checks into your code -- you can call `isBankrupt` with the index of the current player and write the function like this:

```
function isBankrupt(p) {
  // p = the current player
  if (player[p].money <= 0) {
    console.log(player[p].name + ' ' + 'is Bankrupt');
  }
}
```